# Adding a list of objectIds to an array in a collection (ref)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user and doctor collection/model. here's the file it is in

```
module.exports = function(mongoose){
    var User = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {type : String, unique : true},
        password : String,
        nameOfOrg : String,
        workers : [],
        doctors : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : Doctor}],
        patients : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : Patient}]
    })

    var Doctor = mongoose.Schema({
        name : String,
        address : String,
        parentOrg :[{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : User}],
        patients :[{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : Patient}]

    })

    var Patient = mongoose.Schema({
        name : String,
        DOS : String,
        parentOrg :[{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : User}],
        parentDoctor : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : User}]
    })

    var models = {
        User : mongoose.model("user", User),
        Doctor : mongoose.model("doctor", Doctor),
        Patient : mongoose.model("patient", Patient)
    };
    return models;
}
```

I have a route handler like `doctor/:name` every time I go there I put the param in the db so `doctor/doc1` adds doc1 to the name field in the doctors collection. Well every time that happens Im trying to add the objectId of this newly created document to the doctors array in the users collection. I think that is what you are supposed to do to use populate in the future to keep data separate in different collections then bring the appropriate parts together. Any ways I'm having problems adding the doctors ID to the doctors array in the users collection when I go to the route. here is the routing app.js code

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/pop3");

var models = require("./db")(mongoose);

app.get("/:name", function(req, res){
    var user1 = new models.User({"username": req.params.name})
    user1.save(function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(doc)
        res.send(doc)
        app.locals.user = doc
    })
})

app.get("/doctor/:name", function(req, res){
    var doctor = new models.Doctor({"name" : req.params.name, "parentOrg" : app.locals.user._id})
    // app.locals.user.doctors.push(app.locals.user._id)
    models.User.findOne({"username": app.locals.user.username}).push(doctor._id)
    doctor.save(function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }

        console.log(doc)
        res.send(doc)
    })
});
```

I tried to folow the [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) on populate they show to do a similar thing I think by demoing this:

`aaron.stories.push(story1);
aaron.save(callback);`

I guess arron will be my user that was just saved.

stories will be the doctors field and

story1 will be the doctor.

I just couldn't do it

**EDIT**:: I get this error in the browser window:
`TypeError: models.User.findOne(...).push is not a function`

Comment: Well the error makes sense because a "query" object would not have that method. First you need to return an instance. What is the intent? To add a user to the Doctor object? Into which array? There are also many examples of adding an item to an array that should be very easy to find if you search.

Comment: My intent is to add a list of Objectids to the doctors array inside the user collection upon a visit to the `/doctor/:name` ,the ObjectIds are the id that are assigned to the new doctor when they are created by visiting the mentioned url. I wanted to do it the way the docs from mongoose show but I couldn't set it up right. maybe I have to make the `findOne` part into an instance like you mentioned.

Comment: Like I said. Not very clear since you are operating on the `Doctors` model rather than `User` ( and your question states *"doctors array to doctors model"* ). You are also using a "GET" request. And that is not a restful action or endpoint. You likely want "POST" to "/user/doctors". But the number of problems here has me wondering where to start.